# Create .img of a disk from command line?

Tags: windows-7, disk-utility

I need to create a .bin or .img of a disk from the command line.  I have tried using rawcopy (an .exe that I downloaded from the internet), but that is rubbish.  Does anyone know of other alternatives?

What I am trying to do is to save a RAM-Disk (as a virtual HDD) to my physical HDD as a .img file.  I plan to wrap a GUI around this for easy use.  Heck, if someone knows of a Java or C library that can do this I am open to that, too.

Answer (score 1):

Simjply one suggestion. Using a live-image linux system called [system rescue cd](http://www.sysresccd.org) you might be able to use a programme named [partimage](http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page) which might be helpful. The partimage software offers a command option to be used from the command line (http://www.partimage.org/Partimage-manual_Usage).

Knowing some more the background to what you need the image for would maybe enable us to advice you more properly.You mentioned trying "rawimage", you meant a certain software or something like the `dd` system utility? By stating the desire to use the command line I would assume that you used linux and the before mentioned command.